# Where do you do your validation/business rules?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm making a ASP.NET MVC application using EF4, using the Controller --> View Model --> Service Layer --> Repository --> Data Model (EF) approach.

My question is where does the business logic/validation live at?

Should I be making copies of the domain objects into view objects and validating there? Seems like a lot of extra work to duplicate the domain objects into objects for the view models.

I am using POCO's generated using the T4 templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I put business validation logic (things like username is already taken, cannot wire money because of insufficient funds, ...) in the Service Layer and things like the username fields is required on the view model.

Comment: @Darim Dimitrov: could you provide an example of your validation code inside your Service layer, and how you would perform the validation when using view models? Thanks.

Comment: @Kassem, for view models validation I use the [`FluentValidation.NET`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) framework. For the service validation that will depend on the requirements of the project.

Comment: @Darim Dimitrov: So do you make copies of your domain objects to use in your ViewModels or do you just use the domain objects themselves? I am using POCO's generated from a T4 template as my domain objects.

Comment: @Sam, neither of those two. I design my view models in a such a way to include only the required properties for the given view. So for example I could have a view model that contains properties coming from different domain objects or vice versa have multiple view models bound to the same domain object. AutoMapper does the rest for me.

Comment: @Darim Dimitrov: Do you populate the viewmodel from the controller? Or do you have logic inside the viemodel to get it's data?

Comment: @Sam, yes, inside the controller, and because this logic repeats all over my controllers I use [action attributes](https://github.com/darind/samplemvc/blob/master/src/SampleMvc.Web/Mvc/AutoMapAttribute.cs) that take care of this. You might take a look at a [sample MVC project structure I wrote](https://github.com/darind/samplemvc).

Comment: @Darim Dimitrov - Great sample application. Thanks!! I notice it does not implement a service layer, so you validation is talking place in the ViewModels correct? The service layer would fall between the controller and the repository i assume?

Comment: @Sam, yes my sample application doesn't have a service layer. The service layer comes between the controller and the repositories when you have complex business logic. The service layer could aggregate multiple repositories (which are supposed to do CRUD operations) into a complex business operation demarcating the transaction boundaries as well.

Comment: @Darin - So all of my complex validation is in the service layer. So say I have a CustomerService, my add, edit, delete methods go in there and I do any validation inside those methods before passing it to the repository to persist to the database? Then my controller utilizes the service objects for the given views? So my Customer Controller would use the CustomerService to populate the CustomerViewModel, get the data back from the model, pass it off to the service where it is validated and then sent to the repository to be persisted to the database?

Answer (score 2):

I actually like @Darin Dimitrov's method and this is what I'm currently using on my project. And in order to take advantage of displaying error messages just like you would do with using attributes, you can use a wrapper around the ModelState as explained in [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs).